# Selecting an element with dynamic href value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select an element as below

```
 $('a[href^="#Images_Tab"]')
```

This works fine however what actually need is this that the value of href is dynamic and I need to change the statement something like below;

```
$('a[href^="+hrefVal+"]')
```

I know this statement wrong as I have already tried it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes,

Try,

```
$('a[href^="' + hrefVal + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your string prior to concatination, you need to do something like

```
$('a[href^="'+hrefVal+'"]')
```